# Is this a valid measure which can measure fractals?

Tags: measure-theory

I made up a measure in $\Bbb{R}^n$ which has one parameter $D$ - the dimensionality of the measure. If $D=0$, it counts the points in the set. If $D=1$, it measures the length of the curve. If $D=2$, it measures the area of the plane etc... The used $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra inducted by all closed sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$. I will introduce some helper functions first:

$$
C(A,K,r) = \inf_{R_1,\ldots,R_K\in\Bbb{R},x_1,\dots,x_K\in\Bbb{R}^n}\sum_{i=1}^{K}\frac{\pi^\frac{D}{2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{D}{2}+1\right)}R_i^{D} \\
\text{s.t. K closed balls with centres at $x_i$ and radii $R_i$ cover the set $A$}\\
0<R_i<r \text{ for each $i \leq K$}
$$
The sum inside is a formula to calculate the volume of D-dimensional sphere. If it is impossible to cover the set by given spheres and maximal radius, it calculates the infimum of empty set which is infinity.
$$
\mu_D^*(A)=\liminf_{r\to0}\liminf_{K\to\infty} C(A,K,r)
$$
Here we are trying to cover the set in the most efficient way while allowing the usage of more and more balls and then we are decreasing the maximal allowed radius.
The measure function is then defined as:
$$
\mu_D(A) = \min_{z\in Z}\mu_D^*(A\setminus z)
$$
where $Z$ is a set of all subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ which can be decomposed into countably many subsets for which $\mu_D^*$ is zero.

It can be easily seen that this works similarily to the Lebesgue measure for $D=n$. When the set is a square in more than two dimensions, the other dimensions of the balls are just ignored and each ball counts only as it was 2-dimensional. This way, it should be also able to measure the area of curved planes, length of curves etc.. If someone tries to measure the length of a square, it is infinite. And if someone tries to measure the area of a curve, it is zero.

And nobody prevents us from setting $D$ to a fractional value. It can be then used to measure fractals when $D$ is set to the fractal dimension of the measured fractal.

This could also provide another way of determining the fractal dimension. It could the the $D$ for which the shape has a measure which is bigger than zero and less than infinity.

The question is: Is this a valid measure or I made a terrible mistake somewhere? I didn't find any reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Is this significantly different from the ball covering dimension, which is equivalent to the [box-counting dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension)?

Comment: That assigns a dimension to a shape but it doesn't actually say anything about the size. If you scale a fractal twice, the dimension is the same while the measure changes. If you ask how big is a unit square, I'm not satisfied by the answer that it is a 2D object.

Comment: *but it doesn't actually say anything about the size* --- There is a "measure" associated with the box-counting dimension, namely [Minkowski measure](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Minkowski+measure%22+fractal).

Comment: Can you please find me the definition of Minkowski measure? All I was able to find was someone talking about it but without any kind of definition. Not even the MathWorld https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiMeasure.html has a proper definition.

Comment: The 8th hit (for me) for the search in my previous comment is [Intuition behind the Minkowski dimension and measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2787368/13130) (Mathematics Stack Exchange question) which has a definition of the measure. At this question you'll find the more informative *Related* question [Minkowski Content](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600947/13130). The word "content" is often used instead of "measure" when the numerical function is not countably additive, and googling [Minkowski content](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Minkowski+content%22) gives a better search.

Comment: If $\mu_D^*$ was the same as Minkowski content, would $\mu_D$ be a measure?

Comment: This looks like the [modified box dimension](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22modified+box+dimension%22) in Falconer's [**Fractal Geometry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470848618), but I'd have to look at it carefully to see whether it is exactly that or just similar (I'm pretty busy today with day-job things).